# What should I do if I need to read excel file with number like ="01" using php reader?

Tags: php, excel

How should I do if I need to read excel file with number like ="01" using php reader?

They don't read data like ="variables" .

Should I use any other excel reader?

I know how to handle it in downloading files like that, using "mso-number-format".

Please, help me out.

```
require_once '../../lib/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

$data->setOutputEncoding('utf8');
$data->read('data/'.$_FILES["FILE1"]["name"]);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


for ($i = 2; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++) {


            for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']+1; $j++) {
        $strValue = addslashes(trim(strip_tags($data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j]))); // addslashes , trim, strip_tags

        if ($j ==1) $a = $strValue; // 
        if ($j ==2) $b = $strValue; // 
        if ($j ==3) $c = $strValue; // 
    }

echo $a.$b.$c
```

[image]

Comment: do you mean, if in an excel cell, if you have the 01 number, when you read the file it's reading as 1?

Comment: What Reader are you using? Are you actually using PHPExcel?

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I use PHPExcel.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Actually I use PHPExcel.php. I tried to upload Excel file to insert mysql DB. I have data like "02". and it looks ="02" not to cut off "0". But they don't read data like ="02". they put nothing to DB. IF I don't fix Excel file, just using php upload file. is there anything I can do?

Comment: I have the 01 number, it looks like ="01". I read the file, it's reading it as nothing or blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading a number from an Excel worksheet, then it's likely to be held as a simple number ratehr than a string. Either read it and format it using sprintf(), or str_pad(); or check the number format mask of the cell and apply that to your number.

**EDIT**

It looks like somebody is fudging the workbook to use a formula instead of setting the cell value as a string, or applying a format mask (not particularly sensible).

Looking at the code for Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader (lines 1424-1429) where it handles reading formulae that result in a string value, it doesn't actually set the string value in the cell (which is why you're getting an empty cell value).... this is clearly a bug in the library. Either you'll need to fix this; or switch to an Excel library that can actually read formulae that give a string result value; or fix the original spreadsheet so that it sets the '001' value as a string or a format masked number rather than as a formula.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But phpexcel reads them like nothing or blank.

Comment: Even if I don't change excel file, Can I insert excel data to DB perfectly?

Comment: @phplover - Are you using PHPExcel? Your previous comment says PHPExcel, but your code is using Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader? Please clarify, and show your real code... I know a bit about PHPExcel, but rather less about Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader, and knowing what you're doing will make it easier to help

Comment: Thank you so much! very helpful! I want to vote this up for you. But not enough reputation. Sorry.